# Undefined symbol "nettle_hmac_sha224_digest, nettle_hmac_sha1_update" gnutls compilation

Tags: gnutls

I tried to compile gnutls and it looks like it's missing symbols in nettle.

```
CC       pkix_asn1_tab.lo
CCLD     libgnutls.la
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
nettle_gcm_aes_decrypt              nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(cipher.o)
nettle_rsa_pkcs1_sign_tr            nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(pk.o)
nettle_ecc_scalar_set               nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(pk.o)
nettle_ecc_scalar_get               nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(pk.o)
nettle_sha512_digest                nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(mac.o)
nettle_hmac_sha512_update           nettle/.libs/libcrypto.a(mac.o)
...
...
```

I searched for these symbols in the nettle src and could not find where these symbols are defined.  This is result from my find command.

```
#define hmac_sha512_update nettle_hmac_sha512_update
#define hmac_sha384_update nettle_hmac_sha512_update
./hmac.h
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It seems pointing to where the nettle and hogweed libraries are during configuration will help.

i.e. This is my configure line
./configure --build=x86_64-pc-solaris12 --prefix=/usr/local/lib --libdir=/usr/local/lib CFLAGS="-m64 -I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" NETTLE_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lnettle" NETTLE_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" HOGWEED_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lhogweed" HOGWEED_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"